# Wordpress character encoding issue after upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8

I have a wordpress site hosted on Heroku using nginx, hhvm and mysql.

I was on WP version 4.1 and then upgraded to 4.4.2. Now I see that some of my posts have weird characters (black diamonds with questions marks that you can see below).

[image: weird characters]

Also, when i log in to the wp-admin and try to edit a post, the post editor is completely blank (both visual and text modes), and the wordcount shows 0. However the actual post content is still displayed on the live page and I see in the DB that the posts still exist.

*I've checked the console and this is not because of a javascript error or any sort of jQuery mismatch

I believe this is some sort of character encoding issue, because when I change the encoding settings in chrome to Western ISO-8859-15 the black diamonds go away. The post editor is still broken though.

I've tried changing the character encoding on the database and on the individual tables, but that did not fix the problem. I wonder if this is related to some internal HHVM setting for character encoding. Have not been able to find anything there to change though.

Comment: change the charset in the connection too

Comment: @verhie what do u mean in the connection?

Comment: the mysql connection also has a charset:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @verhie ah OK! I checked and the character_set_connection is indeed Latin1. How can I change this though? I'm unable to remotely manage it with the heroku cleardb addon.

Comment: Using Heroku and clear db on a shared plan you are not allowed to change any of the MYSQL system variables such as character_set_connection or character_set_server. However this also means that this was not what caused the issue. It was definitely caused by upgrading the WP version.